# How does memory usage work in PHP when saving images?

Tags: php, image-processing, memory-management

I'm workin on a script that list all images in one directory and then resize and save in another directory.

In my shared server, I receive this message:

```
Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 600 bytes) in...
```

The question is: If PHP can free the memory after each image creation using image_destroy(), why the while loop that save these images get out of the memory limit?

--

The code just save the images, nothing more. The problem is with the amount of images, not with just one huge image. Each image have no more than 300KB and the script stop in the middle, and there isn't an exact point. Each time it's executed, it stop in some of the images.

```
foreach($images as $image) 
{
    $img = PhpThumbFactory::create($image);
    $img->adaptiveResize(640, 450);
    $img->createWatermark(PATH_TEMPLATE_SITE . 'img/watermark.png');
    $img->save($dirBig . $id . '.jpg','jpg');
}
```

The class used in this script is [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/), and have the destructor:

```
public function __destruct ()
{
    if (is_resource($this->oldImage))
    {
        imagedestroy($this->oldImage);
    }

    if (is_resource($this->workingImage))
    {
        imagedestroy($this->workingImage);
    }
}
```

I alredy have the same issue saving images with other scripts. I think the problem isn't with this class, or other type of data used in the script.

Comment: Post your code.  `image_destroy` only frees the memory related to the internal representation of the image.  If you store other information, it may not be released...  Also, images use a fair bit of memory...  Are you sure you aren't loading any huge images?

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using?

Comment: "How does memory usage work in PHP?" Poorly :p

Comment: See the details now. @meagar I've edited, if you have a more elegant title, please, edit.

Comment: I would add an unset($img) in the foreachloop, usally heavy (and smart) useage of unset keeps the memory low

Comment: @vlad `unset` doesn't actually unallocate anything, it literally just undefines the symbol.

Comment: @meagar: Do you have a reference explaining how `unset` does or doesn't affect garbage collection? I looked around b/c this question piqued my interest, and one of the most well-explained articles I found seems to contradict what you say: http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/10

Comment: I've tried unset(), nothing change, since the variable is automatically unseted in each time the loop ran.

Comment: I have no answer, but some suggestions for experimentation: Use `memory_get_usage` to monitor the actual memory usage. Add a close() method to your image class that does the same as the destructor, so you can call it manually. Try factoring your loop contents into a function `createWatermark ($image, $dir, $id)`. Maybe `$image` going out of scope at the end of the function will cause the gc to kick in... really just grasping for straws, but I'm interested to see what you find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the watermark plugin, that get an instance of the parentclass and put in a private member. I don't know exactly, but removing the private member and treating the parent class just as a parameter, the problem was solved.

I also have add a refresh after 20 images saved.